# How to configure a single flask application to handle multiple domains?

Tags: python, flask

Currently, my flask application (that uses sessions) does the following to handle ONE domain:

app.config.from_object(settings)

and in the settings object:

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".first.com"

What I'd like to do now is to dynamically set the session cookie domain to handle, for example, requests from www.first.com and www.second.com.  Please note that I'm talking about domains but not subdomains.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grepping `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` through Flask's Github repo one can see that it is used like [this](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py#L201):

```
def get_cookie_domain(self, app):
    """Helpful helper method that returns the cookie domain that should
    be used for the session cookie if session cookies are used.
    """
    if app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN'] is not None:
        return app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN']
    if app.config['SERVER_NAME'] is not None:
        # chop of the port which is usually not supported by browsers
        rv = '.' + app.config['SERVER_NAME'].rsplit(':', 1)[0]

        # Google chrome does not like cookies set to .localhost, so
        # we just go with no domain then.  Flask documents anyways that
        # cross domain cookies need a fully qualified domain name
        if rv == '.localhost':
            rv = None

        # If we infer the cookie domain from the server name we need
        # to check if we are in a subpath.  In that case we can't
        # set a cross domain cookie.
        if rv is not None:
            path = self.get_cookie_path(app)
            if path != '/':
                rv = rv.lstrip('.')

        return rv
```

Doing the same thing with `get_cookie_domain(` you'll [see](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py#L336):

```
def save_session(self, app, session, response):
    domain = self.get_cookie_domain(app)
    path = self.get_cookie_path(app)

    ...
```

OK. Now we only need to find out what domain name to use. Digging through [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.sessions.SessionInterface.save_session) or [code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py#L284) you'll see that `save_session()` is called in request context. So you just need to import the `request` object from `flask` module:

```
from flask import request
```

and use it inside `save_session()` to determine domain name for the cookies (e.g. from the `Host` header) like this:

```
def save_session(self, app, session, response):
    domain = '.' + request.headers['Host']
    path = self.get_cookie_path(app)

    # the rest of the method is intact
```

The only time you need to specify cookies domain is when you send them back with response object.

Also bear in mind that `Host` header might be absent.

To wire up the whole thing you'll need to specify your version (subclass) of `SecureCookieSessionInterface`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.session_interface = MySessionInterface()
```

More doc links:

- [Response Object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#response-objects)
- [Session Interface](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#session-interface)

Comment: Hi Twil, I understand most of what you said except the last part.  I can get the domain name by doing:

domain = request.headers['Host']

However, I don't understand what you meant by "and use it inside save_session() to determine domain name for the cookies".  My question is: Once I get the domain name, where/how do I set it? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to flask/python but I got the idea.  I'll try to wire it up later, thank you.

Comment: I was able to get it to work.  Thank you for your help.